# IOS keyboard different language than IOS language

Tags: ios, cordova

Currently I'm working on a Phonegap project which is in Dutch (dit not define a language in the App yet), also the OS is in Dutch.

Now my problem. When I open the keyboard or the camera I see a Done, Prev, Next button in English. Which should be in Dutch.

I have read multiple posts about the `CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations` var, but don't know how to add this property in the info tab of my project. And will this solve my issue?

Also I have read that you can add a Language file, but I just want to have the IOS language inside this buttons. Any way to do this?